# Get Name of group and group's elements in an array

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, series

I have this dataframe:

```
df:
    A       B
0   a       class1
1   b       class12
2   a       class2
3   a       class1
4   b       class13
```

So, I group the df like this:

```
df=df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['B'].count()
```

and I get

```
A    B 
a    class1    2
     class2    1
b    class12   1
     class13   1
```

Then I need to access this values and I was thinking to save them in an array of arrays, so then I can read it easily and represent this data in a table, like this:

```
array = [[a,[class1,1],[class2,1]],[b,[class12,1],[class13,1]]]
```

Which is the best way to do this? Is there another better option?

In my real problem I wont know which groups or group's elements I will have, and after the groupby operation I need to list them all.

Thanks

Comment: What you call `df` (after grouping) is a `Series` with a guaranteed unique `MultiIndex`. Do `df.to_dict()` and that's about as nice as you'll get

Comment: How do you access those values with the format you provided? the resulted series is much easier, for example `df[('a','class1')]` gives you `2` and so on. Or a `dict` as @ALollz suggests.

Comment: @QuangHoang mm, with a for loop? The problem is that i do not know which groups and item groups I will have and I want to list them all. I will edit my question

Comment: You can access the group list by `df.index.values`, which give the list `[(a, class1)...]`, and access the items as commented.

Comment: @QuangHoang,  and how can I access to the A values and save them into a list? in this case: A_values = [a,b]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### succinct

```
[[n, [*d.B.value_counts().items()]] for n, d in df.groupby('A')]

[['a', [('class1', 2), ('class2', 1)]],
 ['b', [('class13', 1), ('class12', 1)]]]
```

If you want lists instead of tuples

```
[[n, [*map(list, d.B.value_counts().items())]] for n, d in df.groupby('A')]

[['a', [['class1', 2], ['class2', 1]]],
 ['b', [['class13', 1], ['class12', 1]]]]
```

---

#### `dict`

```
d = {}
for a, b in df.itertuples(index=False):
    d.setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, 0)
    d[a][b] += 1

[[k, [*map(list, v.items())]] for k, v in d.items()]

[['a', [['class1', 2], ['class2', 1]]],
 ['b', [['class12', 1], ['class13', 1]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).size().reset_index(level=1).apply(list,1).\
    groupby(level=0).\
     apply(list).reset_index().values.tolist()
Out[125]: 
[['a', [['class1', 2], ['class2', 1]]],
 ['b', [['class12', 1], ['class13', 1]]]]
```